# Visual Studio Class Diagram - Show two-way associations as a single arrow?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I'm designing a model in C# and I have classes which refer to and from each other;

```
class Order
{
    public ICollection<OrderItem> ChildItems { get; set; }
}

class OrderItem
{
    public Order ParentOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Now, *I* know that Order->ChildItems is the inverse relationship to OrderItem->ParentOrder. What I can't seem to do is represent that on a class diagram as a single arrow with two arrows, two labels, etc. I can get this;

[image]

but I'd prefer a single arrow to make it clear that there is one relationship going on here. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this not possible under Visual Studio 2015. What I am sure is that the arrows express the navigability of the association. An association with one arrow mean that the relation if navigeable in one direction if you do not arrows it does not necessary mean that the association is not navigeable (it depends). if you have a cross at any end of the association it mean that it is not navigeable. for more info please take a look at page 212 of the UML 2.5 specification http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF/

Usually tools use a different layout when an association is naviageable or not in both direction in order to be able to see the difference directly on the diagram.

[image]

This does not seem to be the case with visual studio.

[image]